# IsNumeric Helper Method for large numbers

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I'm trying to create a simple helper function that determines if a number is truly numeric.  Obviously it should be able to handle 'null', negative numbers, and I'm trying to do this without the help of VB's IsNumeric.  And having just learned LINQ, I thought that would be perfect.

The other thing I'd like is to be able to pass a string, integer, long, or any other type, so I was thinking having an 'object' as a parameter is what I really want.  Sure, I could always convert the type to string before calling the helper method, but is it *possible*?

Here's the code I have so far and all I need to do is be able to change the parameter!  I can't imagine it wouldn't be possible... any ideas?

```
private static bool IsNumeric(string input)
{
if (input == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("input");
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) return false;

int periodCount = 0; //accept a string w/ 1dec to support values w/ a float

return input.Trim()
    .ToCharArray()
    .Where(c =>
    {
      if (c == '.') periodCount++;
      return Char.IsDigit(c) && periodCount <= 1;
    })
    .Count() == input.Trim().Length;
}
```

Comment: Why not just test with the regex (untested, from memory): `@"[-+]?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?"`

Comment: Or use decimal.TryParse or float.TryParse or double.TryParse?

Comment: What do you mean with 'large' numbers? How large is 'large'?

Comment: As a side note, consider using the proper decimal separator according to the culture. And think about cases like "1.000.000,5" or ".9e12" which are valid numeric values to me.

Comment: What is the problem with using IsNumeric?  SO is for actual programming questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things to look at here. First, your code won't work with anything with a decimal.
`return Char.IsDigit(c) && periodCount <= 1;` should be `return (Char.IsDigit(c) || c == '.') && periodCount <= 1;`

Secondly, that is entirely possible. This makes your code accept anything, as you wanted.

```
private static bool IsNumeric(object input)
{
    if (input == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("input");
    string inputStr = input.ToString();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputStr)) return false;

    int periodCount = 0; //accept a string w/ 1dec to support values w/ a float

    return inputStr.Trim()
        .ToCharArray()
        .Where(c =>
        {
            if (c == '.') periodCount++;
            return (Char.IsDigit(c) || c == '.') && periodCount <= 1;
        })
        .Count() == inputStr.Trim().Length;
}
```

However, it's very complicated. A much simpler way to do it would be

```
private static bool IsNumeric(object input)
{
    if (input == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("input");
    double test;
    return double.TryParse(input.ToString(), out test);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  The company I work for always goes for LINQ, even if it makes the code look like it was written in brainf*ck!  But I agree, the 2nd is much more readable.  Do you know what the difference is between your implementation (with object) and the one above that uses `IsNumeric(T input)`?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe?

```
private static bool IsNumeric<T>(T input)
{
    double d;
    return double.TryParse(input.ToString(), NumberStyles.Any,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out d);
}
```

---

```
bool b1 = IsNumeric(1); //<-- true
bool b2 = IsNumeric(1.0); //<-- true
bool b3 = IsNumeric("a"); //<-- false
bool b4 = IsNumeric("3E+10"); //<-- true
bool b5 = IsNumeric("1,234,567.0"); //<-- true
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot, that looks like it's exactly what I'm looking for.  I didn't think you could use "T" as an actual data type -- I'll have to research that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If depends on how big your numbers must be, try these options:

```
return double.TryParse(input, out result);
return decimal.TryParse(input, out result); // Larger numbers than double, but slower.
return BigInteger.TryParse(input, out result); // Very large numbers, but slower and does not support decimals.
```